# Real time object tracking in java(some java API) or C#(emgucv,dshownet,Aforge.NET)

Tags: c#, java, real-time, tracking, emgucv

I am doing a **project** called **user initiated real time object tracking system**. Here, is what I want to **happen** in the **project**:

**1)** Take a continuous stream from a web camera.

**2)** Using the mouse a user can draw a square, around an object of interest.

**3)** Then from there onwards, the square moves along with the object of interest. Thereby, tracking each and every place the object moves hence the term object tracking.

---

**Current Progress**

---

I have used dshownet(.NET wrapper for DirectShow)to take input from the web camera. And I am in the process of splitting the video to frames. I have 4 ways in mind to do the project :

---

**Technique 1**

---

- There is a saved video
- I load it.
- when the video is running, i pause (using a pause button) it, at a particular scene and draw a square on an object.
- And when i press play button the square will move along with the object with no/5 seconds processing time [OR] I will give the application some processing time(e.g. 3 minutes) and then it will play from that point onwards with the tracking taking place.

  ---

**Technique 2**

---

- There is a saved video
- I load it.
- when the video is running i dont pause it but quickly draw a square on an object (when the object is still at some point).
- Then the object will be tracked after that with no processing time. [OR] with some processing time (10 sec delay) making the file to play for a little greater time.

  ---

**Technique 3**

---

- I take an input from a web cam for 1 min.
- Save that video to a file
- And perform Way 1 or Way 2

  ---

**Technique 4** - (Apparently this seems alot **harder**)

---

- Take input from a web cam continuously
- Draw a square around the object without any pausing, when the object shows no movement (for e.g. when a person is sitting down on a chair)
- And then show the tracking by moving the square along with the object with no processing time [OR] slight processing time of 2 secs such that the delay is not significantly apparent.

  ---

**Objects to track :-**

---

Basically I can track anything, since I use the mouse to draw

- I am planning to use the whole body (but if this is troublesome.. next option)
- I would try to track the face of an individual (obviously by drawing the area with a mouse.)

  ---

**Time to code :** 1 and 1/2 months

---

**Progress :** Still getting errors with the splitting. (Someone suggested to start splitting a saved video first, and I am in the process of trying that now)

---

**MY QUESTIONS**

---

1) Which Technique **(out of the four)** could I possibly implement in 1 and 1/2 months time frame ?

2) To code, is **java** + some **java framework** good for this or **C#.net** with **emgucv/AForge.net/Dshownet** [by the way my **knowledge** in **java** is **good** and not so **good** in **C#.net**]??

---

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technique 1,2,3 you could implement in Java using the Java Media Framework and ImageJ libraries. For Technique 4 you are better to implement in C++ or other non-interpreted language given the time constraints.

Comment: Your welcome, it's a bit vague. Very interesting project, good luck.

Answer (score 1):

[This example](http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net/en/examples/pongGame.html) basically implements what you mentioned as **Technique 4**. The user draws a rect around a pattern or object to be tracked. In this case the tracked element is used to control the paddle in the Pong Game. Therefore the user can use objects to play the game in front of camera.

I think it solves the most parts of your problem.

**Screenshot:**
[image]

**Source code:**

```
package video.trackingPong; 

import java.awt.BorderLayout; 
import java.awt.Color; 
import java.awt.Container; 
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent; 
import java.awt.event.MouseListener; 

import javax.swing.JFrame; 
import javax.swing.JLabel; 
import javax.swing.JPanel; 
import javax.swing.JSlider; 
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent; 
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener; 

import marvin.gui.MarvinImagePanel; 
import marvin.image.MarvinImage; 
import marvin.image.MarvinImageMask; 
import marvin.io.MarvinImageIO; 
import marvin.plugin.MarvinImagePlugin; 
import marvin.util.MarvinAttributes; 
import marvin.util.MarvinPluginLoader; 
import marvin.video.MarvinJavaCVAdapter; 
import marvin.video.MarvinVideoInterface; 
import marvin.video.MarvinVideoInterfaceException; 

public class TrackingPong extends JFrame implements Runnable{

    private final static int         BALL_INITIAL_PX=100; 
    private final static int         BALL_INITIAL_PY=100; 
    private final static int         BALL_INITIAL_SPEED=3; 

    private MarvinVideoInterface    videoInterface; 
    private MarvinImagePanel         videoPanel; 

    private Thread                     thread; 

    private MarvinImage             imageIn,  
                                    imageOut; 

    private JPanel                    panelSlider; 

    private JSlider                    sliderSensibility; 

    private JLabel                    labelSlider; 

    private int                        regionPx,
                                    regionPy, 
                                    regionWidth, 
                                    regionHeight; 

    private boolean                    regionSelected=false; 
    private int[]                    arrInitialRegion; 

    private int                        sensibility=30; 



    // Pong Game Attributes 
    private double                    ballPx=BALL_INITIAL_PX,
                                    ballPy=BALL_INITIAL_PY; 

    private int                        ballSide=15; 


    double                            ballIncX=5; 
    private double                    ballIncY=5;     

    private int                        imageWidth,
                                    imageHeight; 

    private Paddle                    paddlePlayer, 
                                    paddleComputer; 

    private int                        playerPoints=0, 
                                    computerPoints=0; 

    private MarvinImagePlugin         findColorPattern, 
                                    flip, 
                                    text; 

    private MarvinImage                imageBall, 
                                    imagePaddlePlayer, 
                                    imagePaddleComputer; 

    private MarvinAttributes        attributesOut; 

    public TrackingPong(){ 
        videoPanel = new MarvinImagePanel(); 

        try{ 
            // 1. Connect to the camera device. 
            videoInterface = new MarvinJavaCVAdapter(); 
            videoInterface.connect(0); 

            imageWidth = videoInterface.getImageWidth(); 
            imageHeight = videoInterface.getImageHeight(); 

            imageOut = new MarvinImage(imageWidth, imageHeight);

            // 2. Load Graphical Interface. 
            loadGUI(); 

            // 3. Load and set up Marvin plug-ins. 
            findColorPattern     = MarvinPluginLoader.loadImagePlugin("org.marvinproject.image.pattern.findColorPattern"); 
            flip                = MarvinPluginLoader.loadImagePlugin("org.marvinproject.image.transform.flip"); 
            text                = MarvinPluginLoader.loadImagePlugin("org.marvinproject.image.render.text"); 
            text.setAttribute("fontFile", MarvinImageIO.loadImage("./res/font.png")); 
            text.setAttribute("color", 0xFFFFFFFF); 

            // 3. Load game images 
            imageBall = MarvinImageIO.loadImage("./res/ball.png"); 
            imagePaddlePlayer = MarvinImageIO.loadImage("./res/paddleA.png"); 
            imagePaddleComputer = MarvinImageIO.loadImage("./res/paddleB.png"); 

            attributesOut = new MarvinAttributes(null);

            // Set up plater and computer paddle properties. 
            paddlePlayer = new Paddle(); 
            paddlePlayer.px=100; 
            paddlePlayer.py=420; 
            paddlePlayer.width=100; 
            paddlePlayer.height=30; 

            paddleComputer = new Paddle(); 
            paddleComputer.px=100; 
            paddleComputer.py=30; 
            paddleComputer.width=100; 
            paddleComputer.height=30; 

            thread = new Thread(this);
            thread.start(); 
        } 
        catch(MarvinVideoInterfaceException e){ 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 
    } 

    private void loadGUI(){     
        setTitle("Video Sample - Tracking Pong"); 

        videoPanel.addMouseListener(new MouseHandler()); 

        sliderSensibility = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 0, 60, 30);
        sliderSensibility.setMinorTickSpacing(2); 
        sliderSensibility.setPaintTicks(true); 
        sliderSensibility.addChangeListener(new SliderHandler());

        labelSlider = new JLabel("Sensibility"); 

        panelSlider = new JPanel(); 
        panelSlider.add(labelSlider); 
        panelSlider.add(sliderSensibility); 

        Container container = getContentPane(); 
        container.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); 
        container.add(videoPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH); 
        container.add(panelSlider, BorderLayout.SOUTH); 

        setSize(videoInterface.getImageWidth()+20,videoInterface.getImageHeight()+100); 
        setVisible(true); 
    } 

    public void run(){ 
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
        int ticks=0; 

        // The game loop. 
        try{ 
            while(true){ 

                ticks++; 
                if(System.currentTimeMillis() - time > 1000){ 
                    System.out.println("FPS: "+ticks+"       "); 
                    ticks=0; 
                    time = System.currentTimeMillis();                     
                } 

                // 1. Get the current video frame. 
                imageIn = videoInterface.getFrame(); 
                MarvinImage.copyColorArray(imageIn, imageOut); 

                // 2. Flip the frame horizontally so the player will see him on the screen like looking at the mirror. 
                flip.process(imageOut, imageOut); 

                if(regionSelected){ 

                    // 3. Find the player paddle position. 
                    findColorPattern.setAttribute("differenceColorRange", sensibility); 
                    findColorPattern.process(imageOut, imageOut, attributesOut, MarvinImageMask.NULL_MASK, false);
                    regionPx         = (Integer)attributesOut.get("regionPx"); 
                    regionPy         = (Integer)attributesOut.get("regionPy"); 
                    regionWidth     = (Integer)attributesOut.get("regionWidth"); 
                    regionHeight    = (Integer)attributesOut.get("regionHeight"); 

                    // 4. Invoke the game logic 
                    pongGame(); 

                    // 5. Draw the detected region 
                    imageOut.drawRect(regionPx, regionPy, regionWidth, regionHeight, Color.red); 

                    // 6. Draw the player and computer points. 
                    text.setAttribute("x", 105); 
                    text.setAttribute("y", 3); 
                    text.setAttribute("text", "PLAYER:"+playerPoints); 
                    text.process(imageOut, imageOut); 

                    text.setAttribute("x", 105); 
                    text.setAttribute("y", 460); 
                    text.setAttribute("text", "COMPUTER:"+computerPoints); 
                    text.process(imageOut, imageOut); 
                } 


                videoPanel.setImage(imageOut); 
            } 
        } 
        catch(MarvinVideoInterfaceException e){ 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 
    } 

    private void pongGame(){ 
        // 1. Move the ball 
        ballIncX*=1.001; 
        ballIncY*=1.001; 
        ballPx+=ballIncX; 
        ballPy+=ballIncY; 

        // 2. Set the player paddle position to the the coordinates of the detected region. 
        paddlePlayer.px = regionPx+((regionWidth-paddlePlayer.width)/2); 

        // 3. Invoke simple computer AI 
        computerAI(); 

        // 4. Check object positions and collisions. 
        checkPaddlePosition(paddlePlayer); 
        checkPaddlePosition(paddleComputer); 
        collisionScreen(); 
        collisionTap(); 

        // 5. Draw the game elements. 
        imageOut.fillRect(horizontalMargin, 0, 5, imageHeight, Color.black);
        imageOut.fillRect(imageWidth-horizontalMargin, 0, 5, imageHeight, Color.black);

        combineImage(imagePaddlePlayer, paddlePlayer.px, paddlePlayer.py); 
        combineImage(imagePaddleComputer, paddleComputer.px, paddleComputer.py); 
        combineImage(imageBall,(int)ballPx, (int)ballPy); 
    } 

    private void checkPaddlePosition(Paddle a_paddle){ 
        if(a_paddle.px < horizontalMargin){ 
            a_paddle.px = horizontalMargin; 
        } 
        if(a_paddle.px+a_paddle.width > imageWidth-horizontalMargin){ 
            a_paddle.px = imageWidth-horizontalMargin-a_paddle.width; 
        }         
    } 

    private void computerAI(){ 
        if(ballPx < paddleComputer.px+(paddleComputer.width/2)-10){ 
            paddleComputer.px-=4; 
        } 
        if(ballPx > paddleComputer.px+(paddleComputer.width/2)+10){ 
            paddleComputer.px+=4; 
        } 
    } 

    private int horizontalMargin = 100;
    private void collisionScreen(){ 

        if(ballPx < horizontalMargin){ 
            ballPx = horizontalMargin; 
            ballIncX*=-1; 
        } 
        if(ballPx+ballSide >= imageWidth-horizontalMargin){
            ballPx=(imageWidth-horizontalMargin)-ballSide; 
            ballIncX*=-1; 
        } 
        if(ballPy < 0){ 
            playerPoints++; 
            ballPx = BALL_INITIAL_PX; 
            ballPy = BALL_INITIAL_PY; 
            ballIncY=BALL_INITIAL_SPEED; 
            ballIncX=BALL_INITIAL_SPEED; 
        } else if(ballPy+ballSide >= imageHeight){ 
            computerPoints++; 
            ballPx = BALL_INITIAL_PX; 
            ballPy = BALL_INITIAL_PY; 
            ballIncY=BALL_INITIAL_SPEED; 
            ballIncX=BALL_INITIAL_SPEED; 
        } 
    } 

    private void collisionTap(){ 
        if(ballCollisionTap(paddlePlayer)){ 
            ballIncY*=-1; 
            ballPy = paddlePlayer.py-ballSide; 
        } 
        if(ballCollisionTap(paddleComputer)){ 
            ballIncY*=-1; 
            ballPy = paddleComputer.py+paddleComputer.height; 
        } 
    } 

    private boolean ballCollisionTap(Paddle a_tap){ 
        if 
        ( 
            ( 
                ballPx >= a_tap.px && ballPx <= a_tap.px+a_tap.width || 
                ballPx <= a_tap.px && ballPx+ballSide >= a_tap.px 
            ) 
            && 
            ( 
                ballPy >= a_tap.py && ballPy <= a_tap.py+a_tap.height || 
                ballPy <= a_tap.py && ballPy+ballSide >= a_tap.py 
            ) 
        ) 
        { 
            return true; 
        } 
        return false; 
    } 

    private void combineImage(MarvinImage img, int x, int y){ 
        int rgb; 
        int width = img.getWidth(); 
        int height = img.getHeight(); 

        for(int iy=0; iy<height; iy++){ 
            for(int ix=0; ix<width; ix++){ 
                if 
                ( 
                    ix+x > 0 && ix+x < imageWidth &&
                    iy+y > 0 && iy+y < imageHeight
                ) 
                { 
                    rgb=img.getIntColor(ix, iy);                 
                    if(rgb != 0xFFFFFFFF){ 
                        imageOut.setIntColor(ix+x, iy+y, rgb); 
                    } 
                } 
            } 
        }         
    } 

    public static void main(String args[]){ 
        TrackingPong trackingPong = new TrackingPong(); 
        trackingPong.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
    } 

    private class SliderHandler implements ChangeListener{
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent a_event){ 
            sensibility = (60-sliderSensibility.getValue());
        } 
    } 

    private class MouseHandler implements MouseListener{
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent a_event){} 
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent a_event){} 
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent a_event){} 
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent a_event){} 

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event){ 
            if(!regionSelected){ 
                if(arrInitialRegion == null){ 
                    arrInitialRegion = new int[]{event.getX(), event.getY(),0,0}; 
                } 
                else{ 
                    arrInitialRegion[2] = event.getX()-arrInitialRegion[0]; 
                    arrInitialRegion[3] = event.getY()-arrInitialRegion[1]; 

                    findColorPattern.setAttribute("regionPx", arrInitialRegion[0]); 
                    findColorPattern.setAttribute("regionPy", arrInitialRegion[1]); 
                    findColorPattern.setAttribute("regionWidth", arrInitialRegion[2]); 
                    findColorPattern.setAttribute("regionHeight", arrInitialRegion[3]); 

                    regionSelected = true; 
                }     
            } 
        }         
    } 

    private class Paddle{ 
        public int px,py,width,height;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[This article fully explains](http://joelbecker.net/blog/video-motion-tracking-2) an algorithm very similar to what you want, and [the accompanying source code is here](https://github.com/voxoid0/java-motion-tracking). You can [see it in action in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2aFDTZlR7DM). The part you would need to add would be, when the user draws a box, to identify which objects (already found by the algorithm) the box is around, and then simply follow the object with that int ID throughout the frames (the algorithm correlates the objects frame-by-frame to know it is the same object throughout the video).

Disclaimer: I'm the author; but I do think this is very useful, and have successfully used the algorithm a lot myself.)

When it comes to commercial computer vision applications, [OpenCV](http://opencv.org) and the [Point Cloud Library aka PCL](http://pointclouds.org/) are your best friends. And articles like the one linked explains how to use tools like OpenCV to accomplish full stack motion tracking. (The pure Java implementation shows how it works down to the individual pixels.)